# convert string to array of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How to convert below String into arrays in javascript

```
var data = "[
  [[1400586475733,-1],
  [1400586535736,-1],
  [1400586595739,-1],
  [1400586655742,-1],
  [1400586715745,-1]],
  [[1400586475733,0],
  [1400586535736,0],
  [1400586595739,0],
  [1400586655742,0],
  [1400586715745,0]]
]";
```

expected output is

```
data[0] = [[1400586475733,-1],[1400586535736,-1],[1400586595739,-1],[1400586655742,-1],[1400586715745,-1]]; ==> of type object Array

data[0][0] = 1400586475733 ==> of type number
data[0][1] = -1 ==> of type number
```

Comment: try it more its a good assignment to self learn.

Comment: @brbcoding: i iterated data and push each item in to new Array. but values inside it are still of type string. unable to get the expected output

Comment: @sraina What Do you mean by `String`? are they having `value=string` or They are Those weird numbers as `String`?

If the latter is true `var num=Math.parseInt(string);` While pushing data in array May help you!

Comment: @putvande thanks, it worked!! i couldnt able to use JSON.parse initially since i was using ie9 where JSON.parse is not supported. later i downloaded json2.js library and got result as expected..

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it out thoroughly, but it should work:

```
var string = "[[[1400586475733,-1],[1400586535736,-1],[1400586595739,-1],[1400586655742,-1],[1400586715745,-1]],[[1400586475733,0],[1400586535736,0],[1400586595739,0],[1400586655742,0],[1400586715745,0]]]";


var dataFromString = string.split(",");

var finalArray = [];

var arrayStartRegEx = new RegExp(/^\[/);
var arrayEndRegEx = new RegExp(/\]$/);


var currentArray = finalArray;

var arrayHistory = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dataFromString.length; i++) {

var currentString = dataFromString[i];

var closingArray = false;

    while(arrayStartRegEx.test(currentString) === true) {
        // Save previous array
        // createArray
        // add to big array
        // currentArray = createdArray
        // remove bracket
        var arr = []
        arrayHistory.push(currentArray);
        currentArray.push(arr);
        currentArray = arr;
        currentString = currentString.slice(1,currentString.length - 1);        
    } 
    while(arrayEndRegEx.test(currentString) === true){  
        // remove bracket
        // add element to array
        // close currentArray
        // currentArray = big array
        currentString = currentString.slice(0,-1);
        if(!closingArray) {
            var string = currentString.replace(/\]/g, '');
            // Use parseFloat if you know it's going to be a float
            currentArray.push(parseInt(string));
            closingArray = true;
        }

        currentArray = arrayHistory.pop();

    } 
    if(arrayStartRegEx.test(currentString) === false && arrayEndRegEx.test(currentString) === false) {
        // add element to array
        currentArray.push(parseInt(currentString))
    }

}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, partially addressed it. i thought there could be some simpler approach.

Comment: Hi @sraina what do you mean by partially addressed it? haven't I solved the problem? I re-edited it so that is converts the strings to ints.

Comment: Hi @sraina, simply do a var array = JSON.parse(data) and you'll get what you wanted.

Comment: Hi @David thanks for the last reply, got expected results using JSON.parse method using json2.js library